# How to add a checkbox in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, checkbox

I have created a dataframe as:

```
import pandas as pd
 
data = [['Ankit'], ['Akshat' ]]
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name'])
```

Now, I want to insert a column `PPA` which has checkbox button as values. So, I have written the code as:

```
import ipywidgets
checkbox_button=widgets.Checkbox(description="", value=False,indent=False)
df.insert(loc = 0,column = 'PPA',value = checkbox_button)
```

But after running the code in jupyter notebook, I am getting the column values of column `PPA` as:
`Checkbox(value=False, indent=False)` but when I run `widgets.Checkbox(description="", value=False,indent=False)` in the jupyter notebook, I get the proper checkbox button.

So, Can anyone please tell me how to get the checkbox button in a column of a dataframe ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend, but you can mix html code to in your data, then use `df.style` to render the HTML:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=['a','b'])
df.insert(loc = 0,column = 'PPA',value = '<input type="checkbox" />')
df.style
```

Output:

[image]

which you can interact with individual checkbox.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Quang Hoang. I think by using df.style, I can only show it because type(df.style) gives "pandas.io.formats.style.Styler". Is there any way to store the checkboxes in a dataframe ?

Comment: @ankit Sorry, I don't know any way. Why do you need to store them in the dataframe though?

Comment: I was scraping a website where some data was present in a table and in this table, one column "PPA" contains checkboxes. According to business requirement, I have to import this tabular data in .csv file. I have imported that data in dataframe but no value was showing in "PPA" column and so, I was trying to insert checkboxes in that column @Quang Hoang

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package:
https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid

It allows you to modify the value of a cell, and then get the modified DataFrame.